# Can't load Leaflet inside Vue component

Tags: leaflet, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a Leaflet map as a Vue component but I am having some difficult getting started. I installed Leaflet through npm

Where am I going wrong? console.log(Leaflet) is returning a Leaflet object but I am having trouble getting the map to expand and render.

Some direction would be appreciated

```
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
    // import leaflet here?
    import Leaflet from 'leaflet';

    export default {
        components: {
            Leaflet
        },

        created() {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(Leaflet);
        },

        ready() {
            this.map = L.map('map').setView([51.959, -8.623], 14);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(this.map);
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -24px;
    }

    /* default legend, layer styling from leaflet template */
    .info {
        padding: 6px 8px;
        font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: white;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .info h4 {
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        color: #777;
    }
    .legend {
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #555;
    }
    .legend i {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple problems in your code:

1. There is not a `ready` lifecycle hook in Vue. Use `mounted()`.
2. You are trying to pass the Leaflet library as a component to Vue, which does nothing since Leaflet is not a Vue component and does not need any sort of registering with Vue.
3. A `map` data property was not declared on the Vue component.
4. There is no problem with importing the library as `Leaflet from 'leaflet'`, but it might be more consistent for yourself or others to declare the Leaflet object as `L from 'leaflet'`.  You can also use: `import { Map } from 'leaflet'`, but then must initialize your Map appropriately: `this.map = new Map("mapContainer")`
5. Prevent potential memory leaks and/or cleanup appropriately by using the `remove()` method on a Leaflet Map Class.  A good spot is within the Vue `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook.

Also, don't forget to import the Leaflet CSS, for example: 
`import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";`

```html
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from "leaflet";

export default {
  name: "LeafletMap",
  data() {
    return {
      map: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = L.map("mapContainer").setView([51.959, -8.623], 12);
    L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.map) {
      this.map.remove();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#mapContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I was new to JS when I posted this question. 2 years later I can confirm this is the correct answer and makes a lot of sense !

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was already provided by [jhickok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114797/3873308) but was insightful for the vue3 composition API as well. The leaflet map can't be instantiated in `setup()` for the same reasons explained.

```js
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { map, tileLayer } from "leaflet";
import { onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Map",
  setup() {
    let container = null;

    onMounted(() => {
      container = map("mapContainer").setView([51.959, -8.623], 12);

      tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(container);
    });

    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
      container.remove();
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#mapContainer {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

first install leafletjs and vue2-leaflet with npm

second copy the code to your component

```
<template>
      <div id="app" v-if="isLoad">
        <l-map style="height: 350px" :zoom="zoom"   :center="center" @click="addMarker"   :max-zoom="maxZoom" :min-zoom="minZoom">
          <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tilelayer>
          <l-marker  :lat-lng="markerLatLng" ></l-marker>
        </l-map>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker} from "vue2-leaflet";
    import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
    import {Icon} from "leaflet";
    
    delete Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
    
    Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
      iconRetinaUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png"),
      iconUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"),
      shadowUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png")
    });
    export default {
      components: {
        LMap,
        LTileLayer,
        LMarker,
      },
    
      mounted() {
        this.mapIsReady()
      },
      data() {
        return {
          isLoad: false,
          url: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
           zoom: 15,
          maxZoom:18,
          minZoom:5,
          center: [35.6892, 51.3890],
          markerLatLng: [35.6892, 51.3890],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        mapIsReady() {
          let self = this
          setTimeout(() => self.isLoad = true, 1500)
        },
        addMarker(event) {
          console.log(event)
          this.markerLatLng = [event.latlng.lat,event.latlng.lng];
        },
    
      },
    };
</script>
```

this code has add marker , max zoom and min zoom for your map

this code used open street map because it's free. you can change it to api.mapbox.com if you want but you need api key or accessToken

Answer (score -1):

I just did this, but I needed basemaps too (bing).

leafletWrapper.js

```
const L = require('leaflet')
require('leaflet-bing-layer')

export default L
```

LeafletMap.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import L from 'leafletWrapper'

export default {
    name: 'leaflet-map',
    props: ['center', 'zoom', 'minZoom', 'maxZoom', 'markers'],
    data () {
      return {
        mapObject: {},
        markerLayer: {}
      }
    },
 mounted () {
      const bingKey = 'foo'

      this.mapObject = L.map(
        "map", {
          center: this.center,
          zoom: this.zoom,
          minZoom: this.minZoom,
          maxZoom: this.maxZoom
        }
      )

      L.tileLayer.bing({bingMapsKey: bingKey, imagerySet: 'Road'}).addTo(this.mapObject)

    },
    beforeDestroy () {
      this.mapObject.clearAllEventListeners()
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: There was no explanation in this response pointing out the errors in the original poster's code.  Mainly, there is no `ready` lifecycle hook in Vue, and `mounted` should be used.